# single quote - how do i output it and see it in source code not &#39;

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I need to output a single quote ('). It needs to be a single quote not &#39 as this is part of a string which is used to supply data to a jquery function.

I use c# to loop through an object to build up a string

```
"var data = [['ItemA',3],['ItemB',1],['ItemC',8]];"
```

I then incorporate this string into a jquery function so that it will be incorporated at the browser. However this does not work. If i look at the source of the generated page I have

```
 var data = [[&#39;ItemA&#39;,3],[&#39;ItemB&#39;,1],[&#39;ItemC&#39;,8]];
```

Which jquery cannot work with. So How do i get the single quotes (') in my string to be still single quotes in the source

I have tried escaping but to no avail.

cheers

Comment: You need to show code and add tags (probably asp.net and maybe razor).

Comment: sorry i dont understand...can you tell me more

Comment: There is no code sample in your post - click "edit" and add some. Also while editing post add proper tags at the bottom (next to C#, javascript...) to specify what server side framework you are using (i.e. WebForms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might need to combine a [verbatim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx#code-snippet-6) string with the [`.Raw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper:

```
@Html.Raw(@"var data = [['ItemA',3],['ItemB',1],['ItemC',8]];")
```

If you're not likely to ever use `\` in the string, you can omit the `@` at the beginning and just use a regular string literal. Using a verbatim string has the advantage of not having to use `\\` to prevent the runtime from trying to evaluate unintentional escape sequences.